# Google spreadsheet lookup

Tags: google-sheets

I need to lookup cell values on multiple sheets (tabs in current sheet) and generate a simple report on a sheet/tab named "REPORT" of the current Google Sheet.

> Sheetname1
>   Lookup column A for X, provide corresponding value in column B on those rows
>
> Sheetname(N)
>   Lookup column A for X, provide corresponding value in column B on those rows

Simple enough, I know, but I am a novice at Google Sheets functions, and it would take me days to figure it out from other sample formulas...

Comment: `=vlookup(X, Sheetname1!A:B, 2, false)` does what you want, except it's not clear why you say "rows" in plural (and "value" in singular). Can you clarify whether multiple rows of those sheets might be matching X, and if so, what do you want to happen in that case?

Comment: Multiple rows of those sheets might be matching X.  If so, they should be listed one row after the other.  Sheetname[1] (line break), matching result 1 (line break), matching result[n] (line break) and Sheetname[n], matching  result 1 (line break), matching result[n] (line break)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) or [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) for this.

```
=filter(Sheetname1!B:B, A:A = X)
```

or

```
=query(Sheetname1!A:B, "select B where A = X")
```